# Display loading animation on the visible part of the page center

Tags: html, css, ember.js

I have a page with a container with a vertical scroll, and I want to add a loading animation on the visible part of page above the container. I tried div with class:

```
.loading-animation {
    height:100vh;
    background: url(img/loading.gif) 50% 50% / 100px 100px fixed no-repeat;
}
```

but it appeared at the bottom of the page, below my container. Then I tried

```
.loading-animation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background: url('img/loading.gif') 50% 50% / 100px 100px no-repeat;
}
```

and this appeared above my container but in the middle of all the page, not the visible area. Any ideas how to achieve this appreciated

**Edit1,** javascript:

```
var loading_animation;

function showLoadingAnimationModal() {
    loading_animation = document.createElement("div");
    loading_animation.style.cursor = "progress";
    loading_animation.className = "loading-animation";

    document.body.appendChild(loading_animation);
}

function hideLoadingAnimationModal() {
    if (loading_animation.parentNode == document.body) {
        document.body.removeChild(loading_animation);
    }
}
```

html template (using emberjs):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <div align="center">
        {{outlet}}

        {{#if errorMessage}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                {{errorMessage}}
            </div>
        {{/if}}
      </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login">
    <div class="container">
    <!--skipped elements-->
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML code

Comment: use a component to display a loading spinner inside/above your `container` element.  Using javascript or jquery to append to document is against the grain in ember.

Answer (score 0):

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84yxvpxw/2/)

css

```
.maindiv{
 position: relative;
}
.loader
{
  position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 10;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.loader span
{
  height:30px;
  width:100px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:auto;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  position:absolute;
  background:#ddd;

}
.scrolldiv
{
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;

}
```

HTMl

```
    <div class="maindiv">
    <div class=loader>
          <span>Loading</span>
    </div>
    <div class="scrolldiv">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but seems this does not work if the page is scrolled to bottom, the div appear at page's top

Comment: ok then you need to use position:fixed and set top left position  dynamic using jquery offset.top of container div and set in loader div